# How to call a data-id inside a span using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that when using CSS it changes to a text and a box, I want to write a value inside the box using jQuery.

How do I call the `data-id`?

```
<li id='phase1'>Create robots that are awesoma<span data-id='phase1'></span></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use attribute selector like :

```
$("#phase1 span[data-id]").text("text you want here");
```

If you want to change the value of the `data-* attributes`, you could use jQuery method **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** for this like :

```
$("#phase1 span[data-id]").data('id', 'value you want here');
```

```js
$("#phase1 span[data-id]").text(" TEXT VIA JQUERY");

console.log('Before value : '+ $("#phase1 span").data('id') );
$("#phase1 span").data('id', 'new value');
console.log('After value : '+ $("#phase1 span").data('id') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id='phase1'>Create robots that are awesoma<span data-id='phase1'></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant "How to get data-id attribute of span ?".

You can simply get data-id attribute's value like this:

`$("#phase1 span").attr("data-id")`

And you can set it like this:

`$("#phase1 span").attr("data-id", "new value")`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use just .data()

```
$('#phase1 > span').data('id');
```

if will return 'phase1'